# postgres 9.4 and unicode in json

Tags: json, postgresql, unicode

I've ended up with some json data imported into the database which contains unicode escapes in the json key. And I can't seem to find a way to address the data. The simplest example is:

select '{"test\u0007":123}'::json->'test\u0007'

Instead of getting 123 back, I get NULL. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The operator takes `json` and `text` operands. In `text`, per the SQL spec, backslash escapes have no significance.

If you want to match that key, you'll need to insert the unescaped text literally in the string, or use a PostgreSQL extension, the `E''` string, e.g.:

```
regress=> select '{"test\u0007":123}'::json ->> E'test\u0007';
 ?column? 
----------
 123
(1 row)
```

The `json` gets compared in its *decoded* form, which is why the original didn't work.

Comment: Thank you! It was driving me insane.